# Python 3's shortest quine. I don't get it

Tags: python, explain, quine

```py
_='_=%r;print (_%%_) ';print (_%_)
```

(Edit: I have recieved your input and fixed the code, thanks for the correction.)

This is the shortest quine you can write in Python (I'm told). A quine being code that returns itself.

Can someone explain this line of code to me as if I know nothing about Python? I use Python 3.x by the way.

What I'm looking for is a character-by-character explanation of what's going on.

Thanks.

Comment: Not seriously: the shortest quine should be an empty text file.

Comment: How is that not a quine? It is a program that prints it's own source code.

Comment: @DanD.: Run it. Compare the output to the source code. It doesn't match.

Comment: The correct quine is `_='_=%r;print (_%%_) ';print (_%_)`

Comment: @user2357112 Friend, dear friend, I'm not an expert by any means. I know how string literals work, but I've never seen something this compressed (seeing as most people want readability (see PEP 8)). I was simply confused as to how this worked, and I'm still learning.

Comment: Using www.thonny.org to step through `_='_=%r;print (_%%_) ';print (_%_)` is a good exercise and highlights thonny's educational power.

Comment: Do note the shortest quine in python is actually 1 byte shorter than this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the correct quine is `_='_=%r;print (_%%_) ';print (_%_)`, using this, let's begin:

The `;` executes to commands in a line, so the following:

```py
_='_=%r;print (_%%_) ';print (_%_)
```

is equivalent to:

```py
_='_=%r;print (_%%_) '
print (_%_)
```

In the first line, `_` is a valid variable name which is assigned the string `'_=%r;print (_%%_) '`

Using python's string formatting, we can inject variable into strings in a printf fashion:

```py
>>> name = 'GNU'
>>> print('%s is Not Unix'%name)

GNU is Not Unix

>>> print('%r is Not Unix'%name)

'GNU' is Not Unix
```

`%s` uses a string, `%r` uses any object and converts the object to a representation through the `repr()` function.

Now imagine you want to print a `%` as well; a string such as `GNU is Not Unix %`. If you try the following,

```py
>>> print('%s is Not Unix %'%name)
```

You will end up with a `ValueError`, so you would have to escape the `%` with another `%`:

```py
>>> print('%s is Not Unix %%'%name)

GNU is Not Unix %
```

Back to the original code, when you use `_%_`, you are actually substituting the %r in the `_='_=%r;print (_%%_)` with itself and the `%%` would result in a `%` because the first one is treated as escape character and finally you are printing the whole result, so you would end up with:

```py
_='_=%r;print (_%%_) ';print (_%_)
```

which is the exact replica of what produced it in the first place i.e. a quine.